# Is there a way to collapse javascript or CSS in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008

It would be nice to have the ability to create 'regions' in js and css files. Much easier to work with. I couldn't find anything on Google about this, but even Dreamweaver can do this.

thanks!

Answer (score 8):

you can **select the block** you want to hide and do **CTRL+M,H** (Edit --> Outlining --> Hide Selection)
With enough time someone could write a macro or adding to identify all functions or objects and outline them all separately.

Comment: This is correct, but every time you close the page, it will clear the outlining.  The same is true of Donut's solution, of course, but because its a macro, you can recreate those outlinings with one key command

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell after a little bit of research, there's no native support in VS2008 for collapsible "#regions" in JavaScript or CSS files... however, [this blog post](http://blog.devarchive.net/2008/04/using-region-directive-with-javascript.html) describes a workaround for JavaScript (and it looks like the example could be extended for use with CSS files as well).