# CSS editor with collapsable regions

Tags: css, ide, editor, regions

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to put collapsable regions in CSS files? Or can someone recommend an alternative (free) editor that offers this?

Comment: I have the same inquiry. I logged this issue at connect.microsoft.com - connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/582149/…. I got a message saying the issue was resolved, but nothing further. Not sure what that all meant? Perhaps they've released an extension for it? I'm quite lost.

Comment: [A duplicate of this question just got answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915868/511529)

Answer (score 1):

In [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) you can do this by typing `M-1 C-x $`. However, it has quite a learning curve.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bemroses.net](http://www.bemroses.net/images/curves.jpg))</sub>

And if you have a mac, you could try [CSSEdit](https://espressoapp.com/). And for windows there's [TopStyle](https://www.htmlvalidator.com/topstyle/). Both support code folding.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer below quite useful. I'm using it in Visual Studio 2010 and while it's not perfect, it hides extra stuff while editing.

[Is there a way to collapse javascript or CSS in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059826/is-there-a-way-to-collapse-javascript-or-css-in-visual-studio-2008)